# Can we dispatch a request in Spring Web?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152946/what-is-onceperrequestfilter).

It's about OncePerRequestFilter. The answer says it's used when

> the request could be dispatched to a different (or the same) servlet using the request dispatcher.

But as far as I know there's only one servlet in Spring Web which is the DispatcherServlet. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

We can define multiple servlets in one spring web application.
DispatcherServlet is the default servlet of spring implements.
Here is a example. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-web-contexts#parent-context